# Identify the source of this white die

Tags: identify-this-game

To which board games does this die belong?

[image: Picture of the die in question]

It is a white die with 2 blank face, two faces with one pip, and two faces two pips.
Been wondering for a while.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Boardgames"? Do you know that they are from two games? Or could they be from the same game?

Comment: The white die looks very much like the dice from Betrayal at House on the Hill, but I have no idea for the black one.

Comment: Incidentally, 'dice' is plural, 'die' is singular, and 'dices' is never correct.

Comment: Please post a separate question for the second die. Make sure to describe/show each face.

Answer (score 12):

[Betrayal at the House on the Hill](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-house-hill) uses 8 dice like that one.

[image: Picture of a BatHotH game being played featuring a few of the dice]

[Betrayal at Baldur's Gate](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/228660/betrayal-baldurs-gate) uses 8 dice like that one.

[image: Picture of the BaBG game's components featuring the dice]

There are surely other games that use these, though [Betrayal Legacy](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/240196/betrayal-legacy) is not one of them.

Answer (score 5):

The die in question is used in the "Betrayal" games, [Betrayal at House on the Hill](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-house-hill), the original game where a group of people explore a haunted mansion, [Betrayal at Baldur's Gate](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/228660/betrayal-baldurs-gate), a version of the game set in the Dungeons and Dragons Forgotten Realms city of Waterdeep, and [Betrayal Legacy](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/240196/betrayal-legacy), though the colors were reversed, white pips on black, where like all legacy games, previous plays affect future games for those players. These dice are used for everything randomized in these games, from combat, to saving throws to triggering the game's "Haunt" the event that shifts the game from the early stage exploration to the late game where, usually, one of the players becomes a traitor and must be in some way defeated for the rest of the players to win, with the traitor winning if they fail.

Other games do use the 0,1,2 six sided dice, like [Mage Wars Arena](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/101721/mage-wars-arena), but as far as I have seen only the Betrayal series of games uses black pips on white dice.

Comment: Betrayal Legacy also uses them.

Comment: @bwarner Right I forgot they made a legacy game, updated.

Comment: @bwarner, No, the one's in Legacy are black. https://boardgamegeek.com/image/4395680/betrayal-legacy